# Finding elements in a site with iframes using Perl selenium

Tags: perl, iframe, selenium-webdriver

Currently I am automating interaction with a website which has iframes. Some without id's also and they are not in same hierarchy. I want to click a `<a> </a>` tag but not able to do so. Also read posts for how to do it in Java but there is nothing to come back to default content in Perl (or I did not find).

Someone having experience on it or having any links to any site explaining this would be very helpful. Please note that I am implementing this in Perl using 
Selenium::Chrome.

Comment: Cross post, already answered at http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1174446

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On proper researching I can answer my query. To switch to a frame we can use following two options:

1. Switching to a frame using its id:

> $driver->switch_to_frame('frame_id');

2. Switching to a frame using xpath to the frame:

> $driver->switch_to_frame($driver->find_element_by_xpath(".//*[\@id='id1']/div[2]/div/iframe"));

3. There is an option to switch to frame using the frame number but it becomes hard in case of sites having two many frames to have a count.

Note: We can only work with web elements present in a frame when we switch to a frame.

Now to switch back to the default frame use:

> $driver->switch_to_frame();

Answer (score 1):

Find iframe then switch to iframe
and use xpath for find iframe:-

```
 e.g. //iframe[@class="value of class"] 

  $element = $driver->find_element('coolestWidgetEvah','id');
  $driver->switch_to_frame('frameName');
```

Let me guess to switch to default content in perl:

```
  $driver->switch_to_frame('defaultcontent');
```

swith to default content is work for java check before use.